# How to enable applets in chromium browser?

Tags: applet, ubuntu-12.04, chromium, npapi

I am trying to enable applets in chromium browser. But, the plugin npapi not going to be installed. I know chromium people disable this java feature from their browser. But, I want to run my applet in chromium browser only. How can I enable java in chromium browser?

Thanks in advance...........

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  You'd have to install an old version.  Sorry.

Comment: Thank you for your response. can u please send the link of old version of google chrome .deb file

Comment: sorry, I have no idea where to find such a thing. I'm sure it's out there somewhere, but I'd have to look same as you.